# Force textview to next line in VStack in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, text, position, padding

I have a frame that's holding 3 separate text elements. The string inside is dynamic in size and at times, the length of the first text element will be too long and will not be fully displaying before hitting my 'blank space' text element. I want the first string element to be fully displayed and just push the 'blank space' text element to the right and or next line if needed. I need to keep the text as 3 separate elements because I need to be able to put a unique background on the blank space element

[image: you can see the first string is cut off with...]

```
    struct MonthView: View {
    @Binding var fontOpacity: CGFloat
    var sSO: shortStoryObject
    var questionNumber: Int
    let idx: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text(sSO.plugInQuestionlist[questionNumber].questionPart1)
                        .font(Font.custom("Arial Hebrew", size: 18))
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
                        .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    
                    Text("fff" + sSO.plugInQuestionlist[questionNumber].missingWord + "fff")
                        .font(Font.custom("Arial Hebrew", size: 18))
                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(fontOpacity))
                        .padding(.bottom, 2) // <- play with distance
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(Color.black).frame(height: 2),
                            alignment: .bottom
                        ).padding(.bottom, 10)
                        .background(MyPreferenceViewSetter(idx: idx))
                }
                
                Text(sSO.plugInQuestionlist[questionNumber].questionPart2)
                    .font(Font.custom("Arial Hebrew", size: 18))
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
                    .padding(.top, 7)
                
                
            }.frame(width: 335, height: 200)
                .background(.teal)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
            

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need something like "flow layout": https://github.com/globulus/swiftui-flow-layout